# ssL HTTPS for windows mobile 6::unable to read transport connection

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

am trying Https ssl connection in my C# application...i am getting
"Unable to read transport connection" for the line 
WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

I am forcing Certificate to be accepted
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

public class MyPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {

public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert,   WebRequest req, int problem)
    {
        return true;

```
}
```

}
Working fine in WM5

may i plz know the wat is goin wrong?plz
thanks in advance

Comment: Somewhere It may depend on the .net framework tha v use...Is it so?
i am using v2.0

Answer (score 1):

Here´s why:

http://blogs.msdn.com/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/11/19/why-net-compact-framework-fails-to-call-some-https-web-servers.aspx